# Distance between rectangle and parametric curve

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry, parametric-functions

Given a 2D parametric curve $(x(s), y(s))$ and a rectangle where each of the four vertices is parameterized $(x_i(t), y_i(t))$, $i \in \{1,2,3,4\}$, how can *Mathematica* compute the distance function $d$ where $d(t)$ is the distance of the rectangle at $t$ to the parametric curve with $s \in [a,b]$? The algorithm should yield $d(t) = 0$ if the rectangle and the curve share a common point.

Here is an example of a parametric curve `{xc, yc}` (parameter `s`) and a rectangle `{{xr1, yr1}, {xr2, yr2}, {xr3, yr3}, {xr4, yr4}}` (parameter `t`).

```
{xc, yc} = {x[s], y[s]} /. 
           NDSolve[{theta'[s] == 1, x'[s] == Cos[theta[s]], 
                    y'[s] == Sin[theta[s]], theta[0] == 0, x[0] == 0, 
                    y[0] == 0}, {theta, x, y}, {s, 0, 10}][[1]];

{xr1, yr1, theta} = {x[t], y[t], theta[t]} /. 
           NDSolve[{theta'[t] == 1 + Sin[12 t], x'[t] == Cos[theta[t]], 
                    y'[t] == Sin[theta[t]], theta[0] == 0, x[0] == 0, 
                    y[0] == 0}, {theta, x, y}, {t, 0, 10}][[1]];

{xr2, yr2} = {xr1, yr1} + 0.05 Normalize[{-Sin[theta], Cos[theta]}];

{xr3, yr3} = {xr2, yr2} + 0.05 Normalize[{-Cos[theta], -Sin[theta]}];

{xr4, yr4} = {xr1, yr1} + 0.05 Normalize[{-Cos[theta], -Sin[theta]}];

Manipulate[
  Show[ParametricPlot[{xc, yc}, {s, 0, 4}], 
    Graphics[Polygon[{{xr1, yr1}, {xr2, yr2}, {xr3, yr3}, 
                      {xr4, yr4}} /. {t -> T}]]], {T, 0.01, 4}]
```

Comment: Can you give an example curve and rectangle?

Comment: You can think of the parametric curves being any InterpolatingFunction with the additional constraint that for any $t$ the four points indeed form a rectangle. I am looking for a Mathematica procedure to compute $d$ efficiently.

Comment: I can think, yes, but can't you share an example? It's hard to propose useful code without an example to try it out on.

Comment: I can add an example. Please give me a little time.

Comment: Is the curve closed? If it's not, then it's hard to define "on which side of the curve the rectangle lies"

Comment: @BlacKow: I removed the "on which side" part.

Comment: When I run the code you posted, it doesn't draw any rectangles.

Comment: @m_goldberg: I improved the code.

Comment: @MichaelE2: I added the `;`.

Comment: @MarkusMüller Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this I think,

You first extract your points from the curve, then define the polygon to be a function of the parameter `T`

```
pts = Cases[ParametricPlot[{xc, yc}, {s, 0, 4},PlotPoints->300], Line[{x__}] :> x, 
   Infinity];

pgon[T_] := 
 Polygon[{{xr1, yr1}, {xr2, yr2}, {xr3, yr3}, {xr4, yr4}} /. {t -> T}]
```

(**edit** I had to add a high `PlotPoints` value to get a better result for this method )
Then you find the RegionDistance between the polygon and all the points on the curve, and return the minimum disance

```
distance[T_] := Min[RegionDistance[pgon[T], pts]]
```

From your `Manipulate` I could see that the square and the curve overlap at `T=0` and at `T=3.33`,

```
distance /@ {0, 2, 3.33}
(* {0., 0.0828211, 0.} *)
```

And you can plot the curve

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another method is to turn the curve into a region and use the method described [here](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/basic-and-formula-regions/minimum-distance-between-two-regions.html), though you need to use `Quiet` to suppress error messages,

```
line = DiscretizeGraphics@ParametricPlot[{xc, yc}, {s, 0, 5}];
pgon[T_] := 
 DiscretizeGraphics@
  Polygon[{{xr1, yr1}, {xr2, yr2}, {xr3, yr3}, {xr4, yr4}} /. {t -> T}]
distance2[T_] := 
 Quiet@MinValue[
   EuclideanDistance[x, y], {x ∈ DiscretizeGraphics@r1, 
    y ∈ pgon[T]}]
```

But this method is **very** slow and gives unsatisfactory results in some spots

```
ListLinePlot[
 Table[{T, distance2[T]}, {T, 0.1, 4, .01}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for detailing two methods.

Comment: @MarkusMüller - glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

One can use `FindMinimum[]` with `RegionDistance[rect]` to get a quick, accurate result.  Speed can be expected here because we have a good estimate for a starting value for `s` in the parameter `T`.

```
Block[{T = 1.}, 
 rect = Polygon[{{xr1, yr1}, {xr2, yr2}, {xr3, yr3}, {xr4, yr4}} /. {t -> T}];
 df = RegionDistance[rect];
 ndf[{x_Real, y_Real}, df_] := df[{x, y}];
 FindMinimum[ndf[{xc, yc}, df], {s, T, 0, 4}]
 ]
(*  {0.0757601, {s -> 0.982383}}  *)
```

Because of the numeric nature of `{xc, yc}` (from `NDSolve`) and the singularities in the distance to a rectangle (from the corners), `FindMinimum[]` sometimes senses possible numeric difficulties, none of which here seem to be significant.  In particular the message `FindMinimum::lstol` is common unless `AccuracyGoal` is reduced.  Also `FindMinimum::reged` occurs when the rectangle goes beyond the end of the curve. (It arises when `FindMinimum` wants to set `s` to a value outside the domain `{0, 4}`.)  The last one can simply be suppressed by `Quiet`. As for the first, one can apply `Quiet` or set `AccuracyGoal -> 3`, say, which would be sufficient for the graphics in `Manipulate[]`.

```
Clear[ndf];
ndf[{x_Real, y_Real}, df_] := df[{x, y}];
Manipulate[
 Show[
  ParametricPlot[{xc, yc}, {s, 0, 4}],
  Graphics[
   Dynamic@ With[{rect = 
       Polygon[{{xr1, yr1}, {xr2, yr2}, {xr3, yr3}, {xr4, yr4}} /. {t -> T}]},
     {
      rect,
      Red, Point[{xc, yc} /.
        Quiet[
         Last@
          FindMinimum[
           ndf[{xc, yc}, RegionDistance[rect]], {s, T, 0, 4},
           AccuracyGoal -> 3],
         {FindMinimum::reged}]
       ]
      }]
   ]
  ],
 {T, 0.01, 4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a lot this nice piece of code.

Comment: @MarkusMüller You're welcome.